# Mysql query for top 3 customer

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query top 3 customers. I have 3 tables:

- Customer table (CustomerID, Company)
- Product table (ProductID, ProductName, Price)
- Order table (OrderID, Date, Amount, CustomerID)

```
OrderID     Date        Amount      CustomerID
19      2012-08-24  20      10043
20      2012-08-24  40      10044
21      2012-08-24  60      10044
22      2012-08-24  80      10042
23      2012-08-24  90      10043
24      2012-08-24  100     10042
25      2012-08-24  50      10041
```

If you see this table:

- 10042 has ordered $180 worth of products
- 10043 has ordered $110 worth of products
- 10044 has order $100 worth of products

How do I query this information like this:

Top 3 Customers

```
CustomerID  Company     Cost of Products Ordered
10042       HP      $180
10043       Acer        $110
10044       Sony        $100
```

Currently I have this mysql but its not displaying as how I want it. Can someone help to point out my mistake?

```
$query = "SELECT 
    CustomerOrder.CustomerID, CustomerOrder.Amount, 
    Customer.Company, 
    count(CustomerOrder.Amount) as total_amount
FROM 
    `CustomerOrder` 
     INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.CustomerID = CustomerOrder.CustomerID
GROUP BY CustomerID 
ORDER BY total_amount DESC LIMIT 3";
```

Currently, i'm getting this:

```
 Top 3 Customers

CustomerID  Company         Cost of Product Ordered
10042       HP          80.00
10043       Acer            20.00
10044       Sony            40.00
```

I'm using this code to display:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>CustomerID</th>
<th>Company</th>
<th>Cost of Product Ordered</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['CustomerID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Company'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['total_amount'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: "Currently i have this mysql but its not displaying as how i want it." Can you show what the query gives you and explain how it differs from what you want?

Comment: Hmm. To me "total" and "count" just doesn't seem to be the same thing...

Comment: @MarkByers i have updated what im getting in my question.

Comment: @user1501784: Your query returns 4 columns, but you show that you only get 3 columns. Your output doesn't seem to match up with your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`:

```
SELECT 
    Customer.CustomerID,
    Customer.Company, 
    SUM(CustomerOrder.Amount) AS total_amount
FROM CustomerOrder
INNER JOIN Customer
ON Customer.CustomerID = CustomerOrder.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customer.CustomerID 
ORDER BY total_amount DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: "but i'm getting error". What error? Also, please don't post code in the comments. Update your question to include all relevant information that is necessary to answer your question.

Comment: the error i'm getting is: Warning: mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\.... on line 57

Comment: ok i added $result = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); and got this error: FUNCTION db.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: @user1501784: Did you add a space after `SUM` but before the `(`?

Answer (score 0):

Use following query... I checked it ...its working

```
select ordr.CustomerID,cust.Company,(Sum(ordr.Amount)) as  'Cost of Products Ordered' from `order` ordr , customer cust where cust.CustomerID=ordr.CustomerID group by ordr.CustomerID order by Sum(ordr.Amount) desc limit 3
```